# Unable to connect my TFS in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am unable to connect my tfs with vs2012 whereas when I use the tfs url in browser I can login successfully in tfs.

When I am trying to connect with TFS in VS it show following error

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the collection name

Remove that image that's a live server!